# Why character of induced representation is integer multiple of character of induced representation in normalizer group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

In literature, I read that if we have a group $G$ and its subgroup $H$, we can induce a representation $D$ of $H$ to $\Delta\equiv\text{Ind}_H^G D$. Their characters have a relation: $$\chi^\Delta(h)=c(h)\chi^{\text{Ind}_H^{N_G(H)}D}(h)$$ for $h\in H$, where $c(h)$ is an integer depending on $h$ and $N_G(H)$ is the normalizer of $H$ in $G$. $c(h)$ can be obtained like this:

1. We decompose $G$ in cosets of $N_G(H)$: $G=\bigcup_\alpha s_\alpha N_G(H)$.
2. $c(h)=\#\{s_\alpha, s_\alpha^{-1}hs_\alpha\in H\}$, where $\#$ denotes number of elements.

I cannot prove this and cannot find a reference. Can anyone help me understand the underlying reason behind this formula?

Comment: As with your previous question, I don't believe this is correct, and it doesn't work when $G=S_4$, $h = (1,2)(3,4)$ and $H=N_G(H) = C_G(h)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt, can you elaborate? This is a major conclusion of the paper.

Comment: Let $\chi$ be the linear character of $H$ with $\chi((1,3,2,4))=1$ and $\chi((1,3)(2,4))=\chi((1,4)(2,3))=-1$. Then $c(h)=3$ so $c(h)\chi(h)=3$, but $\chi^\Delta(h)=1-1-1=-1$. You should check the calculations yourself.